# What was Draco Malfoy's biggest fear?

Tags: harry-potter

If Draco were to be confronted by a Boggart, what would it appear as to him? Was this ever suggested in the books or mentioned by JKR?

Comment: Poor? Un-popular? Harry's friend?

Comment: Possibly his father, as he seems terrified of disappointing him.

Comment: I wonder if his biggest fear could be Lord Voldemort himself, punishing him and his family.

Comment: It must be something scary, if you go by *Prisoner of Azkaban* chapter 6 where Fred recounts Malfoy's reaction when he's met the Dementor on the Hogwarts Express.

Comment: Dementors don't show your greatest fear though, they just force you to relive your worst memories.

Comment: Perhaps being turned into a mouse?

Comment: @Cooper That's hardly relevant. It's in fact the opposite: people are terrified so easily and those with horrible memories are often terrified by them for a reason. Awful memories often involve fear and/or will cause someone to be afraid. And need I mention PTSD?

Comment: @TheAsh I suppose you mean 'ferret'. Unless of course...you're suggesting that maybe he doesn't want to be yet another little animal...

Comment: @b_jonas's Suggestion seems to me the most likely. And more so afraid of his life and his family's life from Voldemort. Rowling sort of suggests this but doesn't directly say it would be his Boggart. But she does write quite a lot about his upbringing, how his life falls apart and how he tries to be a better person than his parents: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy (I don't know if it's enough to truly answer or state that canonically it's Lord Voldemort.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @Slytherincess noted, there's no information in standard canon (books/JKR interviews/Pottermore).

However, the secondary canon (specifically, video games) does contain that information.

Just like 90% of other characters, Malfoy's boggart assumed the form of Voldemort, according to the game *"LEGO Harry Potter: Years 1-4"*.

Comment: Until a more canon source address this, this is likely the only answer we'll have then.

Comment: Great call on the LEGO game! I wouldn't have even thought to check the games, but what's your source? If it's the Wikia, I cast Wadiwasi at you! Anyway, as I was writing my answer, a gut feeling kept telling me Draco's Boggart was probably Voldemort, but without anything to back it up with, I didn't say so because it would've just been a guess on my part. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - you expect me to admit to playing it? No way!

Comment: This is actually simple to explain - you have very little shapes the game shows for Boggart; and assigning everyone who's not main protagonist (Neville/Harry/Ron/Hermione) a unique and easy-to-tell Boggart form would make no sense for game developers

Comment: @DVK - WADIWASI!

Comment: It's not a great source, unfortunately - and it doesn't really make much sense, as that particular game takes place before Voldemort's rebirth. Draco wouldn't have any reason to fear him ... yet.

Comment: Note that Lupin heavily implies in PoA that most people don't have a Voldy-shaped Boggart.

Comment: IIRC, in the book, Lupin stops Harry from going through his turn. He explains that he assumed Harry's fear would be Voldemort, and didn't want the others to have to see him. This would not be an issue if 90% (or in fact, anyone else) had conjured the same imagery. Lego tends to make up a lot, and joke around a fair bit. I don't think it is a good source for canon.

Comment: I would say it's more specific; as I just posted a comment to the question: And more so afraid of his life and his family's life from Voldemort. Rowling sort of suggests this but doesn't directly say it would be his Boggart. But she does write quite a lot about his upbringing, how his life falls apart and how he tries to be a better person than his parents: pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy (I don't know if it's enough to truly answer or state that canonically it's Lord Voldemort.  Maybe you want to integrate it into the answer though; by all means if you want to go ahead.)

Answer (score 11):

As of this writing, Draco Malfoy's Boggart is unknown.

It is not revealed in canon or in the additional information on Draco Malfoy from JKR at Pottermore. No JKR interview I have read or heard has revealed what Draco's Boggart is.

As suggested by **BESW** in chat, perhaps it is a ferret.

Comment: And researching this takes one into abysses of fanfics :(

Comment: @DVK - Ah, yes, the pit of voles.

Answer (score 1):

General non-canon disclaimer here. I would guess that it would be a vision of his parent's disapproval - not just his father, but his mother as well. I would imagine that it is similar to, but the opposite of, the image Harry sees in the Mirror or Erised. But Draco would see his parents either enraged at him, simply disappointed, or completely disowned.

Comment: So Draco's Bogart would be...his own father?

Comment: Or both parents. As the spoiled rich kid doing anything to please his parents (including, but not limited to, murder) I think that disappointing them or becoming disowned would be the one thing he is scared most of.

Comment: More like dead. With himself following shortly. At the hands of Lord Voldemort.

Answer (score 0):

Like many have said, there is no mention of his boggart in the books nor in the movies,however if I were to say what I thought it was (Excluding The Cursed Child) I think it would be **his family (Especially his father)** because he has an expectation that he needs to live up to even though he doesn't want to live up to that family legacy and he knows that no matter what his father will make him do whatever his father wants him to do because if he doesn't do what his father wants they consequences will be great. However, this would be after he realized what he was doing was bad and selfish. If we are talking before he was a good person then I think it would have to be his dad or family being disappointed in him, so again, it reverts back to his dad. In all, his dad is what he fears the most.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Speculative answers are generally frowned upon here unless they have some sort of canon information to back them up. Could you perhaps find some quotes from the books showing that Draco feared his father, and the consequences of disobeying him?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would have been his father. Despite him loving his family and doing horrible things to protect them (Voldemort threatened his and his family’s lives if he didn’t kill Dumbledore), he always seemed as if he was trying to gain the approval of his father. Like a child imitating their parent to make them proud. I think that his boggart would have been Lucius disowning him.

Comment: It would be great if you included quotes or evidence from canon that supports your answer.

Answer (score -1):

As a Draco Malfoy fan since day one, I don't think it's his father, I don't think it's Voldemort either, because he WANTED (at first) the glory of working for Voldemort. I also don't think it'd be disappointment, because up until Half Blood Prince, Draco is very confident, it wouldn't even occur to him that he'd ever fail and something he wanted. I think his biggest fear would simply be:

**Being Poor.**

*I think he'd be heart broken to lose Scorpius after losing Astoria, but he's seen enough death to not be afraid of death. But he's always been rich, even after the war.

Answer (score -3):

Losing Scorpius Hyperion Malfoy and Astoria Greengrass.

Comment: I didn't down vote this but: you might want to provide a bit more elaboration. But the thing is this: I understand what you're getting at; they say parents fear most the harm or death of their child and I totally understand the loss of a spouse being very terrifying concept too. But at the same time I don't think it's that simple. Fear is a strange thing and there are fears hidden in people that are far more terrifying than the loss of a loved one. Whether he has one who can tell but the fact he can compartmentalise himself means it's harder for anyone to say for certain.